# Existence of a subsequence of a bounded sequence that converge in a sequence of continuous linear functionals

Tags: sequences-and-series, weak-convergence

Suppose, $\{y_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in a Banach space $X$, $\{m_j\}$ is a sequence of contiuous linear functionals in $X'$, the collection of all bounded linear functionals on $X$.

Is there a subsequence $\{y_{n_i}\}$of $\{y_n\}$ such that $$\lim_{i \to \infty} m_j(y_{n_i})$$ exists for every $m_j$?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you answer the question if $m_j$ were a constant sequence?

Comment: @Thomas:Thanks for your comment. I tried but got stuck on the case when $m_j$ is an eventually constant sequence.

Comment: But then $(m_j(y_n))_n$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers …

Comment: @Thomas:Sorry， I still can't get it. For each $m_j$, there is a subsequence $\{y_{n_i^j}\}$ such that $\{m_j(y_{n_i^j})\}$ converges, as $i$ goes to infinity. But for every $m_j$, the intersection of the indexes of all subsequences, $\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}}\{n^j_i\}$ could be empty.

Comment: The situation should be familiar to you, if you have come across the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem and its proof: diagonal sequence argument?

Comment: @Thomas:  I haven't learned Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, maybe that's why I got stuck. Thank you for your hint.